# How to fix Firmware_class error at boot screen?

Tags: boot, kernel

It says

firmware_class: See "https://wiki.debian.org/Firmware for information about missing firmware"

[snap-shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuiMx.png)

Comment: See the part "updating firmware"  at the end of the link you posted.

Comment: It looks like your OS is Debian, not Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can update firmware for your specific hardware the link you posted has, at the bottom, a reference to [fwupd](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/fwupd) and that is likely to way to get it updated. Mind that it is also possible you will need to ask the vendor of your hardware to get your firmware. fwupd is just a site that collects all those official firmware updates but depends on the hardware vendor to supply it. Newest version can be find at the [project page](https://github.com/hughsie/fwupd/wiki/Compilation) and more information on their [website](https://fwupd.org/).

From the website:

> The Linux Vendor Firmware Service is a secure portal which allows hardware vendors to upload firmware updates. This site is used by all major Linux distributions to provide metadata for clients such as fwupdmgr and GNOME Software. There is no charge to vendors for the hosting or distribution of content.

From the project page:

> Basic usage flow (command line) If you have a device with firmware
>   supported by fwupd, this is how you will check for updates and apply
>   them using fwupd's command line tools.
>
> ```
> # fwupdmgr get-devices
> ```
>
> This will display all devices detected by fwupd.
>
> ```
> # fwupdmgr refresh
> ```
>
> This will download the latest metadata from LVFS.
>
> ```
> # fwupdmgr get-updates
> ```
>
> If updates are available for any devices on the system, they'll be
>   displayed.
>
> ```
> # fwupdmgr update
> ```
>
> This will download and apply all updates for your system.
>
> Updates that can be applied live will be done immediately. Updates
>   that run at bootup will be staged for the next reboot. You can find
>   more information about the update workflow in the end users section of
>   the fwupd website.

Comment: The error message is showing cause my bluetooth firmware is missing from /lim/firmware/brcm folder just downloaded and copied the required .hcd and it fixes the problem .Thanks though.